# spring mvc vs seam

Tags: spring, comparison, seam

Spring mvc is a framework that has been long time out there, it is well documented and proven technology. A lot of web sites are using spring.

Seam is a framework based on jsf - rich faces implementation.
It has a lot of ajax based components.
It uses some heavy stuff like EJB, JPA.
All of this is prone to errors and this framework is so slow (at my computer it is almost impossible do develop something because it is really slow, especially redeploying on jboss)
But is is very good for back office applications.

Does someone have a professional experience with this two frameworks?
Can you recommend the better one ?
Why?

Regards

Comment: With Seam you can use POJOs instead of EJBs. And what is slow about JPA?

Comment: The whole framework is slow, not jpa. If you test the simplest page with ab compared to other frameworks you  will get 10 times less requests.

Comment: Also for seam. I have looked a lot of seam applications productively. I can easily find errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use both: Spring-MVC (2.5) and Seam

Because Seam uses Java Server Faces Technology (A server-side based Technology), behind the scenes, It is better designed for small and medium applications. (Each JSF view Tree is stored on Session - You can store on client side, but be aware bandwidth issues). But it has some advantages:

Typically web application uses the following path

```
view >> controller >> service >> domain
```

With Seam, you can get

```
view >> service >> domain
```

Or even (by using mediator pattern provided by Seam Framework)

```
No controller, No service

view >> domain
```

Besides that,

- JSF 2 supports JSR 303 - Bean Validation
- You can use Wicket instead of JSF if you want
- Conversation and Business process management support
- Use can use Spring DI if you want

Spring-MVC

It has a powerful web-Tier infrastructure

- Handler Mapping (It chooses which Controller should handle the request)
- View resolver (It chooses which View should render the response)
- It can be used for large applications
- Powerful data-binding
- Spring 3.0 supports Annotation-based Controller (JSR 303 - Bean Validation, coming soon)

But i still not use Spring 3.0 because

- By using (and extending when needed) MultiActionController, i can get convention over configuration without no xml settings to define your Controller (You just need to set up your MultiActionController as @Component)
- SimpleFormController provides similar behavior found in Spring 3.0 annotation based controller

...

About The learning path, i think both are similar.

Comment: `"Because Seam uses Java Server Faces Technology (A server-side based Technology), behind the scenes".` Can you please prove this point? Yes Seam utilize JSF and makes a bridge for it, but you can use Seam without touching JSF or any of the JSF functionalities. It all depends on which filters, servlets and interceptors you enable.

Of course there are tons of in-built components that are JSF specific, but the same is true for security, spring, REST, etc.

Comment: @Shervin You are right when you said: It all depends on which filters, servlets and interceptors you enable. But notice i have included Wicket instead.

Comment: @ArthurRonaldFDGarcia - Do you use seam integrated with Spring or on its own?

Comment: @ziggy Both Seam and Spring has been designed to allow integration with other frameworks and technologies. However, i use both independently.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked professionally with `Seam` and it is a killer framework. It really boosts up your productivity. You can use `POJOs` instead of `EJBs`, if you think `EJBs` are slowing you down. About the deployment, just consider deploying to `Tomcat` instead of `JBoss`. On my machine redeployment in `Tomcat` is done in a couple of seconds. But I still haven't used `Spring MVC` to compare them.

Comment: Do you have any problems with back button? My customer really bother that.

Comment: Back button usage should be deprecated in web applications. It should not be used for the program flow. Otherwise Seam is one of the few frameworks which helps you with the back button. http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/Pageflow_in_Seam-Seam_and_the_back_button.html

Comment: What ide are you using? Do you use jpa ?

Comment: Do you recommend seam? Please compare it with other frameworks you have used previously.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and also JPA. Seam is the first web framework I have used professionaly, so I can't really compare it to others. But I can recommend it, because of its ease of development. I really think it has great future.

Comment: "You can use POJOs instead of EJBs". What version of EJBs are you talking about? EJBs 3.1 are annotated pojos.

Comment: @arg20 - POJO is a broad and unspecific term. What I meant is that using the EJB container is slower than just using a plain Seam component.

Comment: @Petar Minchev - is not as unspecific as you are suggesting. The EJB container is slower because it provides you with multiple services. If you were to implement those services with a plain Seam component, your performance would degrade, just like it does with the EJB container

Comment: @arg20 - If you need those services, use EJB of course:) We agree on all points:)

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Seam for a very large site using POJOS and communicated with web services or Hibernate deployed on Tomcat. We have found that the back button support does not work well or is prone to being specific to implementation patterns. Additionally, there is a tendency for sessions to grow very large if using server side state. Attempts to reduce the session size impact back button support or iframe usage due to reduce number of view states stored in session.  More or less, our issue have all been performance related. The tomcat requires more memory and supports less users when compared to a struts 1.2 or spring mvc. We are using around 50 tomcats to support our userbase.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both SEAM and Spring MVC for a few months.

I prefer Spring MVC to SEAM. BTW I noticed JBoss halted the SEAM3 development.

I found a interesting article about comparison of SEAM and Spring MVC. 
The link is 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-java-ee-lost-and-spring?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29&utm_content=Google+Reader

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used both Seam 3 and Spring 3 frameworks.While Seam 3 is easier to code and has a lot of features supporting session management and transaction management ,the performance is slow.Spring is much faster.